# IntelliJ Idea - Not compiling class - but resolves library

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-19

I have a peculiar problem with IntelliJ

The project libraries are showing as resolved meaning any import from the library works fine. For example, `import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;`

But for the java sources within the module - it fails to import them. Even a simple interface with one method , For example - `public interface X { void go()}`  and a class implementing `public Y implements X` - fails to import X.

I have also an ant build which i run inside docker which compiles the project fine !

The older import of the same project works fine and I am unable to find the difference between the two.

**The ant build runs fine!!. It does not compile any file , I put a next line and save the File - still it will not resolve it !!**

**Community Edition 2019.3**

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Surprise - invaidate cache and restart works !!

Comment: Caches should not affect the compiler, only editor, so it's weird.